# How to update custom meta data based on certain conditions in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, product

I have a some product custom fields in WooCommerce and it works well. Here's the code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_advanced', 'meta_data_custom' );
function meta_data_custom() {

  // 1. Partner ID
  woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
      'id'            => '_idpartner',
      'label'         => __( 'Partner ID', 'woocommerce' ),
      'description'   => __( 'Fill in your partner ID.', 'woocommerce' ),
      'desc_tip'      => true,
      'placeholder'   => __( 'Ex : P1', 'woocommerce' )
  ) );

  // 2. Referral ID
  woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
      'id'            => '_idreferral',
      'label'         => __( 'Referral ID', 'woocommerce' ),
      'description'   => __( 'Fill in your referral ID.', 'woocommerce' ),
      'desc_tip'      => true,
      'placeholder'   => __( 'Ex : R1', 'woocommerce' )
  ) );  
}

// Save custom field
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object_meta_data_custom', 10, 3 );
function action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object_meta_data_custom($product){
    // 1. ID Partner
    if ( isset( $_POST['_idpartner'] ) ) {        
        // Update
        $product->update_meta_data( '_idpartner', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_idpartner'] ) );
    }

    // 1. ID Referral
    if ( isset( $_POST['_idreferral'] ) ) {        
        // Update
        $product->update_meta_data( '_idreferral', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_idreferral'] ) );
    }   
}
```

Both the Partner ID and the Referral ID, must be filled in before the product is published.  All Partner ID already have a referral ID except for (Partner ID == P1). So, I want to fill referral ID automatically other than partner ID P1.

So far I have tried :

```php
function update_meta_data_custom(){
    
    global $product;
    
    $idpartner  = $product->get_meta('_idpartner');
    $idreferral = $product->get_meta('_idreferral');
    
    //Set referral id Obtained from user meta dinamically
    $idreferral = "R13";//examples only

    if(!empty($idpartner)){
        if($idpartner !== "P1"){
            
            //$product->update_meta_data( '_idreferral', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_idreferral'] ) );
            //update _idreferral with $idreferral
        }
        else{
            if(!$idreferral){
                //Give a message to update referral ID or no need to do anything
                //Just in case something by human error
            }
            else{
                //No need to do anything or keep the data
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        //Give a message to update partner ID or no need to do anything 
        //Just in case something by human error
    }
}
```

but not sure how to achieve it.

Can someone walk me through how to do that?

Comment: How do you *"**fill referral ID automatically** other than partner ID P1, obtained from user meta dynamically"*? *"Or how do you it, from user meta dynamically"*? Try to clarify your question, please.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have users with multiple roles including guest, partner, customer. etc. So, P1 is in reality a user id like 2, 13, 29. When I get data from _idpartner, I can get a referral id from the partner id (user_meta). $idreferral just an example but I already have it. Thank you

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I've added extra fields to the user user_meta, specifically for the partner role id_referral. On the other hand, before publishing the product, I have to fill in 2 fields, namely _idpartner and _idreferral. But considering that this _idreferral can be obtained if I know id_partner, I think it's good if I can autofill this _idreferral. So, I just fill in the _idpartner field so that it can minimize human error.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec 

global $product;

$idpartner = $product->get_meta('_idpartner');
um_fetch_user($idpartner);
$idr = um_user('regno_referral');
um_reset_user();


$idref = get_users( array(
 "meta_key" => 'id_referral',
 "meta_value" => $idr,
 "fields" => "ID"
) );    
$idreferral = implode ($idref);

Comment: So if P1 is like a user_id, don't try to set or update product meta data based on a user ID (as the user ID changes all the time)… Is better to build a custom function that will allow you to get the required data based on the user ID when it's required…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec What if the a fixed user_id. This means that if there are clients who sell clothes in our store through our agents or partners, then the partner's user_id will be attached to the product (_idpartner). So in full, I have 3 roles attached to the product. 1. Client ID 2. Partner ID. 3. Seller ID. The client is the owner the clothes. Partners is  make offers with clothes owners. While the seller is our marketing who markets the clothes. The end goal is to calculate commissions and report to these 3 roles

Answer (score 1):

Note that you will need to replace in the second function below, `$referral_id = "R13";` with the code for referral ID obtained dynamically from user meta.

So you can implement your custom metadata update based on certain conditions replacing your current code, with the following:

```php
// Display custom input fields settings to admin single product
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_advanced', 'admin_product_display_custom_input_fields' );
function admin_product_display_custom_input_fields() {
    ## 1. Partner ID 
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => '_idpartner',
        'label'         => __( 'Partner ID', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Fill in your partner ID.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'      => true,
        'placeholder'   => __( 'Ex : P1', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );

    ## 2. Referral ID 
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => '_idreferral',
        'label'         => __( 'Referral ID', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description'   => __( 'Fill in your referral ID.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'      => true,
        'placeholder'   => __( 'Ex : R1', 'woocommerce' )
    ) ); 
}

// Save custom input fields values for admin single product
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'admin_product_save_custom_fields_values' );
function admin_product_save_custom_fields_values( $product ){
    ## 1. Partner ID 
    $partner_id = isset($_POST['_idpartner']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['_idpartner']) : '';
    $product->update_meta_data( '_idpartner', $partner_id ); // Update
    
    ## 2. Referral ID 
    if ( $partner_id === 'P1' ) {
        // Replace with the code for referral ID obtained dynamically from user meta
        $referral_id = "R13"; // <== Your code HERE
    }
    else {
        $referral_id = isset($_POST['_idreferral']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['_idreferral']) : '';
    }
    $product->update_meta_data( '_idreferral', $referral_id ); // Update
}

// Display product custom field admin notice
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'throw_error_admin_notice_Product_custom_fields' );
function throw_error_admin_notice_Product_custom_fields(){
    global $pagenow, $typenow, $post_id;

    if( $pagenow === 'post.php' && $typenow === 'product' && $post_id > 0 ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product($post_id);

        if( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) return;

        $partner_id  = $product->get_meta('_idpartner');
        $referral_id = $product->get_meta('_idreferral');

        if ( empty($partner_id) && empty($referral_id) ) {
            printf( '<div class="notice error is-dismissible"><p>%s</p></div>',
            __( 'The Partner ID and Referral ID have not been saved yet.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        } elseif ( empty($partner_id) ) {
            printf( '<div class="notice error is-dismissible"><p>%s</p></div>',
            __( 'The Partner ID has not been saved yet.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        } elseif ( empty($referral_id) ) {
            printf( '<div class="notice error is-dismissible"><p>%s</p></div>',
            __( 'The Referral ID has not been saved yet.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work

When saving/updating the product, if the Partner ID or/and the Referral ID are empty, an error notice will be displayed.

Comment: Sorry just replied to your message now. I've created a function to override $id_referral and I'm sure the result is correct. ( $id_referral = id_referral(); ). But when I run the code you gave it gives the error message -> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to get_meta() member function on null. However, for the error message it works fine.  Thank you

Comment: I have updated my answer code… It should solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. But the fatal error I mean is: 1. The value of $referral_id is not saving. 2. When editing (example) product title and then press the update button, the screen display displays a fatal error. To point 1 I added $product->save_meta_data(); and it stores value. For point 2 I have not found a solution